# Install SUMO on Ubuntu 16.04 VBox

Tags: makefile, build, sumo

During the installation of SUMO (https://github.com/eclipse/sumo) on Ubuntu 16.04 VBox I face an error when i want to build (when i use make i get an error):

```
[ 80%] Built target _libsumo
[ 80%] Linking CXX shared module ../../../../bin/liblibsumojni.so
/usr/lib/java/bin/javac: 1: /usr/lib/java/bin/javac: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
src/libsumo/CMakeFiles/libsumojni.dir/build.make:147: recipe for target '../../bin/liblibsumojni.so' failed
make[2]: *** [../../bin/liblibsumojni.so] Error 2
make[2]: *** Deleting file '../../bin/liblibsumojni.so'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1484: recipe for target 'src/libsumo/CMakeFiles/libsumojni.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/libsumo/CMakeFiles/libsumojni.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions please ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a problem with your java version. Unless you really need those Java bindings you can simply disable them when calling cmake like this:

```
cmake -DENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS=OFF ../..
```

(this assumes you have a build dir like build/cmake-build as in the docs).

Comment: thank you so much!! it was helpful. can you please tell me how you knew about the issue ? i mean how you thought that the problem is because of java version ? I don't have experience to read and understand the issue according to the error message.

Comment: It was more or less a guess. Swig seldomly generates Java code which is not compilable at all, it often just depends on a certain version. It may very well be that a different swig version would generate valid code also for your Java version.

Comment: thank you again! I hope this will help another beginners in the future.